# Am I using ctypes correctly to pythonify this struct?

Tags: python, c++, c, dll, ctypes

I'm trying to talk to [this DLL](http://www.theimagingsource.com/en_US/support/downloads/details/icimagingcontrolcwrapper/) using python's ctypes. Many of the functions take or return an `HGRABBER` type:

```
typedef struct HGRABBER_t__ { int unused; } HGRABBER_t;
#define HGRABBER HGRABBER_t*
```

(the full header file can be viewed [here](https://github.com/samuellab/mindcontrol/blob/master/3rdPartyLibs/tisgrabber.h)). Here's an example of a function prototype that returns an `HGRABBER` type:

```
HGRABBER __stdcall IC_CreateGrabber();
```

Here's my attempt at implementing this struct in python, and using it to call that function from the DLL:

```
import ctypes as C
class GrabberHandle(C.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('unused', C.c_int)]

dll = C.windll.LoadLibrary('tisgrabber_x64.dll')
dll.create_grabber = dll.IC_CreateGrabber
dll.create_grabber.argtypes = []
dll.create_grabber.restype = GrabberHandle
my_handle = dll.create_grabber()
```

This seems to work, but I'm worried that I'm doing this wrong. I'm not experienced with C, and I don't think I understand the `typedef` and `#define` statements which define the `HGRABBER` type. **Am I calling `IC_CreateGrabber` correctly?**  Should I have defined GrabberHandle to be a pointer to a struct, instead of a struct?

Thanks for reading, please let me know if I can clarify my question somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that you actually want a `POINTER` to the `Structure`, not the `Structure` itself.

Translating the C into English, being very loose (in a way that would be dangerous if you were trying to learn C but is good enough for using `ctypes`):

- The `struct` defines a type named `struct HGRABBER_t__`, as a structure with one `int` in it.
- The `typedef` defines a type named `HGRABBER_t`, as a synonym for `struct HGRABBER_t__`.
- The `#define` defines a type named `HGRABBER` as a pointer to `HGRABBER_t`.

So, your `GrabberHandle` is the equivalent of `HGRABBER_t`; the equivalent of `HGRABBER` is:

```
GrabberHandlePtr = C.POINTER(GrabberHandle)
```

So you want this:

```
dll.create_grabber.restype = GrabberHandlePtr
```

It may be hard to debug the difference. A C struct with nothing but an `int` in it looks identical to an `int` in memory. And on Win32, an `int` and a pointer are both 32-bit values. And an int named `unused` is likely to be filled with meaningless garbage, making it hard to distinguish it from a pointer you've accidentally treated as an int. So everything will look fine, until you segfault 30 lines later in your code and have no idea what's wrong. :)

Comment: Your answer seems like the correct one to me, but the other answer contradicts you. Normally I can tell who is right by running code, but not this time it seems, for the reasons you mention (no crash til way later). Is there a way to prove which answer is right, or should I go with my gut here?

Comment: @Andrew, the unused `int` is unnecessary. What matters is the address in the pointer, which is probably for a C++ object. Setting the result to a 4-byte struct is wrong on a 64-bit system; that truncates the pointer address. You can instead use `c_void_p`, but for better type safety stick with a pointer to a struct. You don't need to define `_fields_`. You can use `HGRABBER = POINTER(type('HGRABBER', (Structure,), {}))`.

Comment: @eryksun: Good suggestion about using a pointer to an empty struct to represent an "opaque handle" of the kind frequently used in Win32 APIs.

Answer (score 1):

This library does what you are trying to do: https://github.com/morefigs/py-ic-imaging-control :)

But to answer your question, the library uses the code:

```
from ctypes import *
import os

class GrabberHandle(Structure):
    pass
GrabberHandle._fields_ = [('unused', c_int)]

# set and check path
dll_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'),
                        'Documents\\The Imaging Source Europe GmbH\\TIS Grabber DLL\\bin\\win32\\tisgrabber.dll')
with open(dll_path) as thefile:
    pass

# open DLL
_ic_grabber_dll = windll.LoadLibrary(dll_path)

# create grabber
create_grabber = _ic_grabber_dll.IC_CreateGrabber
create_grabber.restype = POINTER(GrabberHandle)
create_grabber.argtypes = None

# get handle
handle = create_grabber()
```

Edit: changed code to use a pointer to `GrabberHandle` as per abarnert's answer as this is correct. However, in this particular case I have found no practical difference (with the 32-bit DLL), probably because the `GrabberHandle` structure is so simple.

Comment: I agree the code works, but I get access violations when I make trivial modifications to the code, and I think this might be related. Also I'm using 64 bit, and I think you're using 32.

Comment: Unrelated, but while you're here: what's up with the set_format method? It would crash if called, but doesn't the documentation say it's mandatory to set the sink format before acquiring an image?

Comment: Do you need to use the 64-bit DLL? Are you using 64-bit Python? They must match. I'm using 32-bit Python and DLL (on 64-bit Windows 7).

Comment: You found a typo bug in `set_format()`, I've fixed it now on GitHub.

Comment: Right, but that means it was never called? And doesn't the documentation say you have to call it? I'm running into an issue where calling set_format doesn't seem to actually set the format, yet I seem to be able to snap images anyway. Is the documentation wrong?

Comment: Also I'm just pretending that COLORFORMAT is an int because I don't know how to do an enum with ctytpes. Maybe this is fine, or maybe this is why my calls to get_format always return 5 (NONE in the enum).

Comment: Is your contact info online? It might help me a lot to discuss this further, if you have time.

Comment: And yeah, I'm using 64 bit everything.

Comment: C, being a weakly-typed language, requires that casting an object pointer to an appropriate-sized integer and then casting it back before using it is guaranteed safe. On your 32-bit Python, an `int` is an appropriately-sized integer for any object pointer. So, you get away with it.